# Check existence of 'filename' in a chosen folder

Tags: matlab, file, if-statement, directory

I use

```
dir = uigetdir;
```

to ask the user for a foldername. In the next step, I want to make an if-else-statement, that checks if there is a file with a specific file name in that folder. A little bit like the following (not working) code:

```
if exist(dir/'filename','file')==true
  load([dir '/filename.mat']);
end
```

Comment: Since you're dealing with files, you might consider not overloading the `dir` function

Comment: @horchler you are perfectly right! I'm going to update the code in my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify your code as follows:

```
%dir = uigetdir; Not to overload the "dir" command
sel_dir = uigetdir;

filename='my_file.mat'

if(exist(fullfile(sel_dir,filename),'file') == 2)
  load(fullfile(dir,filename));
else
   disp('file not found')
end
```

`fullfile` built-in function create the full pathname of your file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've update the code accordingly to the comment by @horchler. Replaced `dir` with `sel_dir`

Comment: `dir` is a MatLab command that list a directory. MatLab allows the user to use the names of a command as a variable, nevertheless, if you do that, the command will not longer work because, now, `dir` (in your case) is the variable. You can check if the name you want to assign to a varaible is a command name by using `which <variable_name>.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strcat()`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) to concatenate directory name and file name:

```
if exist(strcat(dir, '/filename.mat'), 'file')
  load(strcat(dir, '/filename.mat'));
end
```